# Automatic merge of pull requests on Github without the merge bubble

Tags: git, github

The "This pull request can be automatically merged [Merge pull request]" button in github is great -- except that it creates merge bubbles.

Is there a way to use this button/functionality in github without it creating merge bubbles?

Comment: Not sure I've ever heard the term "bubble" before (in relation to git); I'm assuming it means "commit"?

Comment: @chharvey Please google "merge bubble". :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*And..* they fixed it!

See [GitHub's blog on squashing your merge commits](https://github.com/blog/2141-squash-your-commits)

If you go to the settings for your repository, you'll see a "Merge Button" section (under Options). It will have 2 buttons available:

**Allow merge commits**
  Add all commits from the head branch to the base branch with a merge commit.

and

**Allow squash merging**
  Combine all commits from the head branch into a single commit in the base branch.

If you uncheck the first option (and left the *Allow squash merging* checked), PR "merges" will result in rebase and squashes.

Comment: Except that squash is not equivalent to rebase + fast-forward merge in the case where you have several commits that you want to keep separate...

Comment: @FlorentGuillaume You're absolutely correct! Unfortunately, that has nothing to do with avoiding a merge bubble or not. ;D

Comment: I'm just saying that *Allow squash merging* has (obvious) side effects besides avoiding merge bubbles.

Answer (score 40):

No.

The [git blog](https://github.com/blog/843-the-merge-button) says using this button you always get an --no-ff merge (no fast-forward merge).

You'd have to do a manual merge if you don't want merge bubbles:

```
git checkout master
git remote add cameronmcefee git://github.com/cameronmcefee/Spoon-Knife.git
git fetch cameronmcefee 
git merge cameronmcefee/my-branch
git push origin master
```

Comment: You can set up your repo to fetch pull requests without adding a remote: https://help.github.com/articles/checking-out-pull-requests-locally

Comment: we did simple automation to do fast-forward merge on github https://github.com/checkstyle/checkstyle/blob/master/fast-forward-merge.sh

Comment: What is the reason for `--no-ff` in this case?